# Child component not triggering rendering when parent injects props with differnt values

Tags: reactjs

Here are my components:

App component:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {Component} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import {MonsterCardList} from './components/monster-list/monster-card-list.component'
import {Search} from './components/search/search.component'

class App extends Component
{
  
  constructor()
  {
    super();

    this.state = {searchText:""}
  }

  render()
  {
    console.log("repainting App component");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <main>
          <h1 className="app-title">Monster List</h1>
          <Search callback={this._searchChanged}></Search>
          <MonsterCardList filter={this.state.searchText}></MonsterCardList>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _searchChanged(newText)
  {
    console.log("Setting state. new text: "+newText);
    this.setState({searchText:newText}, () => console.log(this.state));
  }
}

export default App;
```

Card List component:

```
export class MonsterCardList extends Component
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data:[]};
    }
    
    componentDidMount()
    {
        console.log("Component mounted");
        this._loadData();
    }

    _loadData(monsterCardCount)
    {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
            method: 'GET',
           }).then( response =>{
            if(response.ok)
            {
                console.log(response.status);
                response.json().then(data => {
                    let convertedData = data.map( ( el, index) => {
                        return {url:`https://robohash.org/${index}.png?size=100x100`, name:el.name, email:el.email}
                    });
                    console.log(convertedData);
                    this.setState({data:convertedData});
                });
            }
            else
                console.log("Error: "+response.status+" -> "+response.statusText);
            /*let data = response.json().value;
            
            */
          }).catch(e => {
              console.log("Error: "+e);
          });
          
    }

    render() 
    {
        console.log("filter:" + this.props.filter);
        return (
            <div className="monster-card-list">
                {this.state.data.map((element,index) => {
                    if(!this.props.filter || element.email.includes(this.props.filter))
                        return <MonsterCard cardData={element} key={index}></MonsterCard>;
                })}
            </div>
        );
        
    }
}
```

Card component:

```
import {Component} from "react"
import './monster-card.component.css'

export class MonsterCard extends Component
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render() 
    {
        return (
            <div className="monster-card">
                <img className="monster-card-img" src={this.props.cardData.url}></img>
                <h3 className="monster-card-name">{this.props.cardData.name}</h3>
                <h3 className="monster-card-email">{this.props.cardData.email}</h3>
            </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

Search component:

```
import {Component} from "react"

export class Search extends Component
{
    _searchChangedCallback = null;

    constructor(props)
    {
        super();
        this._searchChangedCallback = props.callback;
    }   
    
    render()
    {
        
        return (
            <input type="search" onChange={e=>this._searchChangedCallback(e.target.value)} placeholder="Search monsters"></input>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that I see how the text typed in the input flows to the App component correctly and the callback is called but, when the state is changed in the _searchChanged, the MonsterCardList seems not to re-render.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you are using state `filter` in `MonsterCardList` component:  `filter:this.props.searchText`.But you only pass a prop `filter` (`filter={this.state.searchText}`) in this component. So props `searchText`is undefined.

I saw you don't need to use state `filter`. Replace `this.state.filter` by `this.props.filter`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that. Was playing with code a lot and left that part here. I have edited the question to acess the props in monster-card-list instead of the state. Shouldn't it be updating now? Because from the App coponent the state is changed and a new filter prop is injected. But still not triggering the render method.

Answer (score 0):

`_loadData` will get called only once when the component is mounted for the first time in below code,

```
componentDidMount()
{
    console.log("Component mounted");
    this._loadData();
}
```

when you set state inside the `constructor` means it also sets `this.state.filter` for once. And state does not change when `searchText` props change and due to that no rerendering.

```
constructor(props) 
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {data:[], filter:this.props.searchText};
}
```

If you need to rerender when props changes, use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) 
{
  if (this.props.searchText !== prevProps.searchText) 
  {
    this._loadData();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Notbad, check this out !!

Comment: Well, this is not really what I wanted. I don't want to fire loadData everytime the component has to update. The idea is to do this once (this is just a test, the retrieving code from the api won't be in this component later). So, I have changed the access to the access to the props in the render method as the user below stated (thanks!). From my understanding, when the App component gets the data from the search component and does a setState, this should trigger the moster-card-list render that would be using the new props injected. But this doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I found what was happening. It wasn't a react related problem but a javascript one and it was related to this not been bound to App class inside the _searchChanged function.

I we bind it like this in the constructor:

```
this._searchChanged = this._searchChanged.bind(this);
```

or we just use and arrow function:

```
_searchChanged = (newText) => 
{
    console.log("Setting state. new text: "+newText);
    this.setState({filter:newText}, () => console.log(this.state));
}
```

Everything works as expected.

Comment: Didn't notce it. You don't need to bind like this. You can use arrow function notation which automatically binds the function to the this contex.